# Remove fortunes-husse package only

Tags: linux-mint

I'd like to remove only the `fortunes-husse` package on linux mint. Is there a way to remove this that won't remove all parent packages?

Comment: [Linux Mint Bug #807982 - mintsystem incorrectly depends on fortunes-husse](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/807982) *On Linux Mint 11 I tried `sudo apt-get remove fortunes-husse`. Unfortunately mintsystem depends on this package and removal would cause mintsystem and 7 other packages to be removed.*

Comment: @karel, I understood that much. Can I just `rm /usr/bin/fortunes-husse` or something?

Comment: Instead of removing fortunes-husse you could make it into a backup of itself by renaming it using: `sudo mv /usr/bin/fortunes-husse /usr/bin/fortunes-husse-backup`

Answer (score 0):

The results of apt-cache rdepends fortunes-husse show that fortunes-husse has no reverse dependency packages.

```
$ apt-cache rdepends fortunes-husse
E: No packages found
```

No other packages depend on fortunes-husse, so you can simply uninstall it.

```
sudo apt remove fortunes-husse
```